# Normalize centrality measures

Tags: graphs-and-networks

How I can normalise centrality measures? Can I use Normalize function? I give example of unnormalized measures

```
g = GridGraph[{5, 5}];  
ClosenessCentrality[g] // Short  
BetweennessCentrality[g] // Short  
DegreeCentrality[g] // Short
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Everybody any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize" here?  Can you define it?

Comment: measures between 0 and 1

Comment: So why don't you just divide by the `Max`imum then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize will give you vectors whose Norm is one.

```
g = GridGraph[{5, 5}];

ClosenessCentrality[g] // Normalize // Norm
```

> 1.

```
BetweennessCentrality[g] // Normalize // Norm
```

> 1.

```
DegreeCentrality[g] // Normalize // Norm
```

> 1

Comment: so I can use Normalize to convert my vector in normalised vector

Comment: Take an arbitrary real vector then `n = 10; Array[x, n] // Normalize // Norm // FullSimplify[#, Element[Array[x, n], Reals]] &` gives 1

Answer (score 2):

You just has to use the definition of normalized centrality measures, for example, to betweenness centrality you must divide the vector by (n-1)(n-2) for the undirected case.